# Google Voice reply code

Tags: gmail-api, google-voice

When someone sends me an sms to my Google Voice number I get an email to the associated gmail account, from a specially generated email address. If I reply to this email, the sender will get an sms from my Google Voice number.

The From address consists of sender number, my number, and a unique code.

My question is, is there a way to generate this email address without requiring that sender to actually send me an email?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita No code, hence no error. Is it possible, and how? Did you read the question or just look for a code snippet?